# How can I programmatically tell if a filename matches one of a set of brace-expanded glob patterns?

Tags: bash, wildcards

I would like to tell if a string `$string` would be matched by a glob pattern `$pattern`.   `$string` may or may not be the name of an existing file.  How can I do this?

Assume the following formats for my input strings:

```
string="/foo/bar"
pattern1="/foo/*"
pattern2="/foo/{bar,baz}"
```

I would like to find a bash idiom that determines if `$string` would be matched by `$pattern1`, `$pattern2`, or any other arbitrary glob pattern.  Here is what I have tried so far:

1. `[[ "$string" = $pattern ]]`

   This almost works, except that `$pattern` is interpreted as a string pattern and not as a glob pattern.
2. `[ "$string" = $pattern ]`

   The problem with this approach is that `$pattern` is expanded and then string comparison is performed between `$string` and the expansion of `$pattern`.
3. `[[ "$(find $pattern -print0 -maxdepth 0 2>/dev/null)" =~ "$string" ]]`

   This one works, but only if `$string` contains a file that exists.
4. `[[ $string =~ $pattern ]]`

   This does not work because the `=~` operator causes `$pattern` to be interpreted as an extended regular expression, not a glob or wildcard pattern.

Comment: The issue you're going to run into is that `{bar,baz}` isn't a pattern. It's parameter expansion. Subtle but critical difference in that `{bar,baz}` is expanded very early on into multiple arguments, `bar` and `baz`.

Comment: If the shell can expand parameters, then surely it can tell if a string is a potential expansion of a glob.

Comment: give this a try a=`ls /foo/*`  now you can match in a

Comment: @Patrick: after reading through the bash man page, I have learned that `foo/{bar,baz}` is actually a brace expansion (not a parameter expansion) while `foo/*` is pathname expansion.  `$string` is parameter expansion.  These are all done at different times and by different mechanisms.

Comment: @jayhendren @Patrick is right, and then you learned that your question ultimately is not what the title leads one to believe. Rather, you want to match a string against various kinds of patterns. If you wanted to strictly match versus a glob pattern, the `case` statement performs Pathname Expansion ("globbing") as per the Bash manual.

Comment: Also there is `compgen -G "<glob-pattern>"` for bash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no general solution for this problem.  The reason is that, in bash, brace expansion (i.e., `{pattern1,pattern2,...}` and filename expansion (a.k.a. glob patterns) are considered separate things and expanded under different conditions and at different times.  Here is the full list of expansions that bash performs:

- brace expansion
- tilde expansion
- parameter and variable expansion
- command substitution
- arithmetic expansion
- word  splitting
- pathname expansion

Since we only care about a subset of these (perhaps brace, tilde, and pathname expansion), it's possible to use certain patterns and mechanisms to restrict expansion in a controllable fashion.  For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -f

string=/foo/bar

for pattern in /foo/{*,foo*,bar*,**,**/*}; do
    [[ $string == $pattern ]] && echo "$pattern matches $string"
done
```

Running this script generates the following output:

```
/foo/* matches /foo/bar
/foo/bar* matches /foo/bar
/foo/** matches /foo/bar
```

This works because `set -f` disables pathname expansion, so only brace expansion and tilde expansion occur in the statement `for pattern in /foo/{*,foo*,bar*,**,**/*}`.  We can then use the test operation  `[[ $string == $pattern ]]` to test against pathname expansion after the brace expansion has already been performed.

Answer (score 11):

I don't believe that `{bar,baz}` *is* a shell glob pattern *(though certainly `/foo/ba[rz]` is)* but if you want to know if `$string` matches `$pattern` you can do:

```
case "$string" in 
($pattern) put your successful execution statement here;;
(*)        this is where your failure case should be   ;;
esac
```

You can do as many as you like:

```
case "$string" in
($pattern1) do something;;
($pattern2) do differently;;
(*)         still no match;;
esac
```

Comment: Hi @mikeserv, as indicated in the comments and the answer that I provided above, I have already learned that what you say is true - `{bar,baz}` is not a glob pattern.  I have already come up with a solution to my question that takes this into account.

Comment: +1 This answers the question exactly as given in the title, and the first sentence. although the question later conflates other patterns with shell glob patterns.

Answer (score 3):

As Patrick pointed out you need a "different type" of pattern:

```
[[ /foo/bar == /foo/@(bar|baz) ]]


string="/foo/bar"
pattern="/foo/@(bar|baz)"
[[ $string == $pattern ]]
```

Quotes are not necessary there.

Comment: Ok, this works, but strictly speaking, it doesn't answer my question.  For instance, I would like to consider patterns that are coming from another source, i.e., the patterns are out of my control.

Comment: @jayhendren Then you probably have to first convert the incoming pattern to those bash accepts.

Comment: So all you've really done is transformed my question from "how do I tell if a filename is a potential expansion of an expression" to "how do I convert normal bash-style filename patterns to bash-style extended glob patterns."

Comment: @jayhendren Considering that what you want seems impossible "all you've really done" sounds a bit strange to me but maybe that's just a foreign language thing. If you want to ask this new question then you must explain what the input patterns look like. Maybe it's a simple `sed` operation.

Comment: What I mean is this: your proposed solution works, but it introduces a new problem: how to transpose patterns from one form of expression to another. I have figured out the answer to my question and posted it here as an answer.

Comment: @HaukeLaging is correct. People coming here to figure out how to match against glob patterns (aka "Pathname Expansion") are liable to get confused, as I did, because the title says "shell glob pattern" but the contents of his question use a non-glob pattern. At some point, jayhendren learned about the difference but his initial confusion is what caused Hauke to answer the way he did.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to manually perform brace expansion using `eval`. It seems to work under most use cases, but I am not sure if there is any other caveats.

```
match() {
    exp=($(eval echo "$1")) # try to expand braces
    if [ ${#exp[@]} -eq 1 ]; then
        [[ "$2" == $1 ]]
        return $?
    else
        # match succeeds if one of the expanded patterns succeeds
        for expanded in ${exp[@]}; do
            if match "$expanded" "$2"; then
                return 0
            fi
        done
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Example usage:

```
file="abc.jpg"
pattern1="abc.{pdf,jpg}"
pattern2="*.{pdf,jpg}"
pattern3="*.jpg"
pattern4="[abcdef]??.jpg"

match "$pattern1" "$file" && echo "succeeds" || echo "fails"
match "$pattern2" "$file" && echo "succeeds" || echo "fails"
match "$pattern3" "$file" && echo "succeeds" || echo "fails"
match "$pattern4" "$file" && echo "succeeds" || echo "fails"
```

Output:

```
succeeds
succeeds
succeeds
succeeds
```

Comment: Try `match "*" hello.txt`, or `f='foo bar.txt'; match "$f" "$f"`. Or `pat='$(uname -a >&2)'; match "$pat" hello.txt`. The first two break because of word splitting and globbing in that `exp=($(...))` assignment ([Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)).

Answer (score 0):

If it's about checking whether `$string` is among the filepaths that result from the expansion of the glob stored in `$pattern` (bearing in mind that, as others have said `{foo,bar}` is not a glob operator), then with `zsh`, you could do:

```bash
if ()(($#)) $~pattern(NY1e['[[ $REPLY = $string ]]']); then
  print -r -- "$string is among the result of the $pattern glob expansion"
fi
```

With `bash`, you could always use a loop:

```bash
among() (
  string=$1 pattern=$2 IFS=
  shopt -s nullglob extglob
  for file in $pattern@(); do
    [[ "$string" = "$file" ]] && return
  done
  false
)
```

```
if among "$string" "$pattern"; then
  printf '%s\n' "$string is among the result of the $pattern glob expansion"
fi
```

(with `extglob` enabled which enables a subset of ksh's extended operators, you can use things like `foo/@(foo|bar)`. We add `@()` to the pattern above to force glob expansion; without it, `among foo foo` would return true even if `foo` didn't exist. That means however that patterns ending in `/` don't work (as in `among /bin/ '/*/'`).

In `ksh`, brace expansion happens to be performed upon parameter expansion in addition to split+glob as long as `noglob` is not enabled and `braceexpand` is not disabled. `ksh93` also has a `~(N)` glob operator as an equivalent to `zsh`/`bash`'s `nullglob`, so there you could do:

```bash
function among {
  typeset string="$1" pattern="$2" IFS= file
  set -o braceexpand +o noglob
  for file in ~(N)$pattern; do
    [[ "$string" = "$file" ]] && return
  done
  false
}
```

And `among foo/bar 'foo/{bar,baz}'` would return true as long as a `foo/bar` file exists.

Note that ksh's extended glob operators are not recognised when they are in the result of other expansions (so that `a='@(x)'; echo $a` outputs `@(x)` as POSIX requires).

Note that in all of those, `among .foo '*'` or `among /etc/issue '*'` or `among /usr/local/bin '/*/bin'` would return false even though the strings match the patterns.

Answer (score -1):

For those coming here with a similar question for zsh instead of bash:

```
[[ $string = $~pattern ]] && print true
```

Or

```
case $string in
  ($~pattern) print A;;
  ($~pattern2) print B
esac
```

Or its shorter form:

```
case $string {
  ($~pattern) print A;;
  ($~pattern2) print B;;
}
```

The `~` forces the contents of the variable to be interpreted as a pattern as if the `globsubst` option had been enabled. Without it `[[ $string = $pattern ]]` is just byte-to-byte string equality comparison.

Replace `;;` with `;|` for all patterns to be tested instead of stopping at the first match.

Like for bash and most other shells, `{foo,bar}` is not a glob operator in `zsh`. `zsh`'s glob alternation operator is `(foo|bar)`, like in regexps except that the parenthesis are required.

Comment: The question states that the bash shell will be used.